# Is there a planet walk with the positions of Voyager 1 and 2?

Tags: voyager, planet, solar-system, space-art

There are a lot of walks like the [Sagan Planet Walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagan_Planet_Walk) (see [the list on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_System_model)).

But are there any of these walks that include the position of the Voyager space probes?

Some days ago I was preparing for a 10 km run and I calculated the positions of the planets along the trail when Pluto is located at the end. At this scale, the Voyager probes would be at about 35 and 29 km.

Comment: I disagree with the off-topic votes.  "Planet walks" and other solar system models are great tools for solar system exploration outreach and thus fit within the topic of space exploration.

Comment: Although it doesn't have Voyager, within the [Sweden Solar System model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweden_Solar_System), the Voyager spacecraft should be somewhere around the Arctic Circle now (Sun and rocky planets are all in Stockholm, Jupiter at Stockholm Airport, Termination Shock is at the Institute for Space Physics in Kiruna), which would be a fun place to put a little plaque.  I'm pretty sure nobody has ever run the full >1000 km of the model though!  Tourist office in Stockholm couldn't even help me locate the inner planets, they knew nothing about the model :(

Comment: The problem is that the Voyager probes are still moving, which makes it rather difficult. I think the best you could do is something as you suggested, calculate yourself the distance to where the probes are and continue beyond a standard model. There are a number of solar system models to scale out there, of various distances.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_System_model

Comment: Of course Voyager is still moving, but we only have to increase the distance in the model by about 2.5 % for each year. From 35 km by 900 m each year, 2.5 m each day and 0.1 m per hour. A speed invisible to the naked eye, but you will see a difference if you come back a day later.

Comment: An extension of existing planet walks by a virtual position of Voyager 1 on a computer displayed map could be a nice part of the 50th anniversary celebration of the Voyager mission. Several maps in different scales should be displayed to visualize the daily movement by 2.5 m.

Comment: @Uwe consider adding the `space-art` tag? I also think this question is on-topic for similar reasons [expressed above](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/23550/#comment67239_23550).

Answer (score 3):

I found one including the position of Voyager 1, the Solar System lawn model of [Griffith Observatory](http://www.griffithobservatory.org/exhibits/solar_system_lawn_model.html)
Very remarkable model including the elliptical orbit of Pluto.

But a solar system model in Houston should in my opinion include the position of Voyager 1: [Voyage in Houston](http://voyagesolarsystem.org/community-network/houston-texas-voyage-mark-i/)

Comment: These are great! I haven't been back since Leonard Nimoy (and of course others) remodeled the Griffith Observatory visitor's center, now much larger and underground. However I noticed that the bust of [James Dean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Dean) is just beyond where the orbit of Pluto passes within that of Neptune. Looks like the invisibility cloak of some visiting aliens didn't make it all the way to the ground though; https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBQBq.jpg, also https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8pvA.jpg